# SQL*Plus output to a text file on single line

Tags: sql, oracle, output, sqlplus

I am running this SQL*Plus command to output the results to a text file:

```
set pagesize 200
spool d:\TRHMIBS\audit_ufm_report.txt

SELECT to_char(systimestamp,'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') as now , to_char(COUNT(*)/(10*60),'999.99') as processing_rate 
  FROM AUDIT_TRANS U 
  WHERE U.LAST_UPDATED > SYSDATE -10/1440 
/
spool off 
exit;
```

I am receiving the output below. I am trying to have the row on a single line, like `20150902 5:00:00   36.51`. Is it possible to do this?

Output file:

```
NOW                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------     
PROCESSING_RATE                                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20150902 15:00:00                                                               
  36.51
```

Comment: Set the linesize really big.

Answer (score 3):

SQL*Plus uses as default returned column metadata which can be tricky when functions returning variable text are used. You can manually define format for any column using

```
COLUMN NOW FORMAT A20 HEADING "Now"
COLUMN processing_rate FORMAT 999D99 HEADING "Processing rate"
```

Headings are optional.

Check the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_six.htm#SQPUG016.